# Rolling back Oracle Transction if not committed within certain minutes

Tags: oracle, locking, rollback

We've had problems on production where some developers have not committed the transactions which resulted in locks. Is there a way for me rollback a transaction if it complete and not committed within certain number of minutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create `PROCEDURE kill_long_transaction` and run a procedure manually or run this procedure on a schedule.
If you limit inactive time in the profile, all inactive sessions will be marked as killed. This can be inconvenient when the developer writes code or the session is rarely used by the application.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE kill_long_transaction (time_transaction in number default 30 )
   IS
BEGIN

  FOR loop_kill IN (
 select
   s.sid,s.serial#
from
   v$session     s,
   v$transaction t
where
 s.taddr = t.addr
and  round((sysdate -t.start_date)*60*24 ,2) >time_transaction
)
  LOOP
      execute immediate 'alter system kill session '''||loop_kill.sid||','||loop_kill.serial#||''' ';

  END LOOP loop_kill;


END;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could create a new or alter a current database profile to limit the users idle time:

```
Create Profile Idle_Time_Out limit idle_time 30;
```

and then assign the user to that profile:

```
Alter User some_user Profile Idle_Time_Out;
```

The above profile will limit some_user to 30 minutes of inactivity at which point their session will be disconnected and any uncommitted transactions will be rolled back.